# Adding first name and last name to devise sign up form

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using Rails 4 and I'm trying to add *first name* and *last name* fields to the sign up process. I'm using Devise to handle authentication.

I've added first_name and last_name columns to my user model through a migration. I also added the following to my application_controller.rb file:

```
before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

protected

def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me) }
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:email, :password, :remember_me) }
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password) }
end
```

However when I sign up, the first_name and last_name field can be left blank and even when they are populated the values are not saved to the user object.

How can I:

1. Force those fields to be required on sign up? I tried adding 'validates_presence_of :first_name, :last_name, :email' to the user model but had to remove it since the form for some reason always thinks the first_name and last_name fields are blank.
2. Update devise create action so that it saves the values passed in through the devise/registrations/new.html.erb file?
3. I have a Person model that i want to associate with this user (associations are created successfully and i have forms that edit both person and user fields but not sure how to build that into the devise sign up process.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This article should help:
http://www.jacopretorius.net/2014/03/adding-custom-fields-to-your-devise-user-model-in-rails-4.html It shows how to customise RegistrationsController

Comment: Thanks Jonas. ^ This is the correct answer to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is covered in the devise wiki

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-with-something-other-than-their-email-address

Comment: Thanks but that references attr_accessible so that doesnt seem to be a rails 4 writeup. Do you know if thats Rails4?

Comment: I think it's generic enough that you should be able to surmise the changes needed for rails 4.  Really, just move the attr_accessible into a params.permit call in your controller, right?

Comment: It's weird you selected this answer as a correct one. The original question was about adding two additional fields to Devise sign up form. This answer is about allowing users to log in with username (not email). The comment by Jonas ^ provides a link that answers the question precisely.